# Confusing jQuery behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, xhtml

I've got a basic HTML page, consisting of just:

```
<body id="body">
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"    type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/three.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/stats.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/application.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

as the main body of a `index.html` page, and where the content of `application.js` is:

```
function init() {
    var container = $('div');
    container.attr('id', 'container');
    $('body').append(container);
    alert('Container: ' + $('#container').length);
}

$(function() {
    init();
});
```

So this is clearly some very basic code, I create a div and append it to the body. However, the `alert` call I make returns `0` and when I inspect the DOM tree via chrome, no div is added.

As I'm adding the script files to the bottom of the `<body>` tag, and calling `init()` from a jQuery `ready()` block, why would this be happening? Seems like such a basic and simple task.

*Note: No errors are being thrown in chrome's console*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `var container = $('div');` isn't **creating** a DIV, it's **selecting** one. If you want to *create* a container then do `var container = $('<div></div>');`

As a result, your current code returns an empty jQuery object, but you don't notice as jQuery plays nicely with them, and just does nothing.

Comment: Can't believe I've been so silly, thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div')
```

This selects all `<div>` elements in your page using an element selector.
You don't have any `<div>` elements, so it returns an empty jQuery object.

The rest of your code therefore has no effect.

It sounds like you actually want to create a new element:

```
$('<div />')
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, knowing the shortcut to Ian's answer is also helpful.